# The parameterized query expects the parameter ###### which was not supplied

Tags: c#

I am trying to run this code but I get the error "The parameterized query expects the parameter @faid which was not supplied". At least based on my knowledge, this code looks good. I am using VS 2010 on Windows 7 with SQLEXPRESS as backend.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
       string getDataQuery;
        lcFaid = "70464917-967b-4796-9483-3b0b4b004a3e";

        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ccsConnectionString);

        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        getDataQuery =
            "SELECT customer,custtrack,ackdate FROM famain WHERE faid = @lcFaid";

        SqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        masterDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

        masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
        masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@lcFaid",
            SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 36, "faid").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;


       masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = getDataQuery;
       masterDataAdapter.Fill(data, "famain");
```

Comment: So you have a parameter called `@lcFaid` but the error message says it's looking for a parameter called `@faid`? That's odd.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you never use the variable `lcFaid`. Perhaps you meant to use that instead of the literal string `"faid"` (which not a GUID at all)?

```
masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@lcFaid",
        SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 36, lcFaid).SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this - but I would

- **first** set the command's query text (which defines what parameter there will be)
- only **then** add the parameters to the collection

Something like this:

```
string getDataQuery =
        "SELECT customer,custtrack,ackdate FROM famain WHERE faid = @lcFaid";

SqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
masterDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand .Connection = sqlConnection1;

// first set the query text
masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = getDataQuery;

// after that, define the parametesr
masterDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters
  .Add("@lcFaid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 36, "faid").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
```

Also, as "Gabe" has pointed out in his comment - the error message references a parameter `@faid`, but you're defining and setting a parameter called `@lcFaid` - why??

Comment: Thanks! Just to save time, I created a stored procedure and called it to get the same data. I will however continue to work with this code in my spare time and post my results here.