# The parameterized query expects the parameter '@Id', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am writing a software I use method (parameters.add) but when I am adding data to a database I get the error below:

> The parameterized query expects the parameter '@Id', which was not
>   supplied.

I saw several topic but I can't solve my problem.

[The parameterized query expects the parameter ###### which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687189/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

[The parameterized query expects the parameter , which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993251/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

I put c# code and stored procedure code below:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TranscactionAccountNumber;Data Source=DESKTOP-5DJFFQP";
            string name = txtName.Text;
            int shomarepeygiri = int.Parse(txtShomarePeygiri.Text);
            string date = dtpDate.Shamsi;
            decimal mablagh = decimal.Parse(txtMablagh.Text);
            string comment = txtComment.Text;
            using (cn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertTransaction", cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShomarePeygiri", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shomarepeygiri;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mablagh", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = mablagh;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comment", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comment;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date;
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction Added Successfully..", "Register Transaction", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }


        }
```

---

```
Create procedure InsertTransaction
(
@id int,
@Name nvarchar(100),
@ShomarePeygiri int,
@Mablagh decimal(18, 0),
@Comment nvarchar(MAX),
@PersianDate varchar(10)

) 
AS
Insert Into TransactionTable(id,[Name],ShomarePeygiri,Mablagh,Comment,PersianDate)
 values (@id,@Name,@ShomarePeygiri,@Mablagh,@Comment,@PersianDate)
```

Comment: you aren't giving a value to Id. you're just declaring it. You give all the other parameters a value, but not that one.

Comment: Seems like you didn't provide a value for parameter: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.Int);`

Comment: You don't set any value for the @ID parameter. Second, a command that calls a storedprocedure should say it in its CommandType property

Comment: This maybe shouldn't be an issue but... make it a capital " i ".

Comment: You are not assigning any value to `@Id`. If this value is intended to be auto-assigned, you should remove it entirely, from your procedure and your insert.

Comment: because "@id" is a primary key I don't want to fill it manual.

Comment: Did you set the IDENTITY property on the database column ID for your `TransactionTable` ? If yes, then this field is populated automatically from your database engine and you don't need that parameter and you don't need to insert anything in your stored procedure for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.Int);
```

You are Adding a parameter, but you are not giving a value for it. Because of that you are receiving this error.

If the ID column is Auto Incremented just remove it from the Stored Procedure.

**EDIT**: If you don't know how to create the column auto incremented check this answer:
**[Auto increment primary key in SQL Server Management Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991894/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012)**

Comment: @alexshiro okay, if the ID is auto incremented like I wrote in my answer, just remove it from the stored procedure and don't give this parameter in the code. The sql server will auto increment the ID number and fill the ID for you.

Comment: @mybrithname,but, i get the error below:Procedure or function 'InsertTransaction' expects parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.

Comment: @alexshiro you need to remove the ID param from the code and from the stored procedure. The error tell you that you don't supply value from your name parameter

Comment: I removed 'ID' .but ,I get the error now : Procedure or function 'InsertTransaction' expects parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.

Comment: @alexshiro if you removed the id from both places, Check if you are giving value from Name parameter, this is what the error.

Comment: i get it ,I'm so sorry I forgot to write cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Answer (score 2):

Alter your procedure as below

```
Alter procedure InsertTransaction
(
@Name nvarchar(100),
@ShomarePeygiri int,
@Mablagh decimal(18, 0),
@Comment nvarchar(MAX),
@PersianDate varchar(10)
) 
AS
Insert Into TransactionTable([Name],ShomarePeygiri,Mablagh,Comment,PersianDate)
values (@Name,@ShomarePeygiri,@Mablagh,@Comment,@PersianDate)
```

Comment: I removed 'ID' .but ,I get the error now : Procedure or function 'InsertTransaction' expects parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.

Comment: I get the error in c#. this line of code:cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: is your id column is auto incremented?

Comment: If yes then remove  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.Int); this line from your code

Comment: I removed completely ID  from c# code and stored procedure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128055/discussion-between-alex-shiro-and-mansi-chaudhari).